# useState doesn't change the state in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[Mycode] (https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-kowalevski-fp00l?file=/src/App.js)

I'm practicing React by making todo-list app.
I want my input empty when i hit Enter. but it didn't work.

here is my whole code :

```
const Todo = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{text}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

const InputText = ({ addTodo }) => {
  const [txt, setTxt] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!txt) return;
    addTodo(txt);
    setTxt("");
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setTxt(e.target.value)}></input>
    </form>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const addTodo = (text) => {
    const newTodos = [...todos, text];
    setTodos(newTodos);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="todo-list">
        {todos.map((val, idx) => {
          return <Todo key={val + idx} text={val} />;
        })}
        <InputText addTodo={addTodo} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

line 17 on the link, setTxt(""); doesn't change state of txt.
how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a "controlled" component since you are not using the `value` property on the `input`.

Try

```
      <input type="text" onChange={e => setTxt(e.target.value)} value={txt} />
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to set the input value to your state.

Try something like

```js
<Input type="text" onChange={(e) => setTxt(e.target.value)} value={txt}/>
```

I hope it helps.